# Array of buttons: change property

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an array of buttons, like this:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
butt2 = new Button[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    butt2[i] = new Button();
    int names = i;
    butt2[i].Name = "b2" + names.ToString();
    butt2[i].Location = new Point(525 + (x * 31), 70 + (y * 21));
    butt2[i].Visible = true;
    butt2[i].Size = new Size(30, 20);
    butt2[i].Click += new EventHandler(butt2_2_Click); //problem lies here (1)
    this.Controls.Add(butt2[i]);
}

private void butt2_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // want code here
}
```

I want to change the back color of the button when clicked. I was thinking of passing `i` to be able to do this:

```
butt2[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: thanks, tried it does the job

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
private void butt2_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  Button pushedBtn = sender as Button;
  if(pushedBtn != null)
  {
     pushedBtn.BackColor = Color.Green;
  }  
}
```

And this holds for most UI events, the 'object sender' parameter refers to the control that 'sent'/'fired' the event.

To learn more about C# event handling, I would start [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Also, here is [a SO question about GUI event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500500/basic-gui-event-handling-questions-c-sharp), answered nicely by Juliet (accepted answer).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, that did it, where can I read about this kind of things?

Comment: @lookie I edited my answer with some links you might find useful. Good luck with learning the trade :D.